# ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'flask_session' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask, sqlalchemy

I have the following code from CS50w, the file is `application.py`

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, session
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
```

but when I hit `python3 application.py` the following error comes up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_session import Session
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'flask_session' (unknown location)
```

I am sure that I have installed all the packages

```
~/Documents/cs50_web/project1 » pip3 install Flask-Session                                                                                                              macone@Macs-MacBook-Pro
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Session in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cachelib in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Session) (0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask-Session) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.8->Flask-Session) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.8->Flask-Session) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.8->Flask-Session) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.8->Flask-Session) (0.24)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask>=0.8->Flask-Session) (1.1.1)
```

same thing happens for `sqlalchemy` but it comes slightly different

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'
```

but it is also installed

```
~/Documents/cs50_web/project1 » pip3 install sqlalchemy                                                                                          macone@Macs-MacBook-Pro
Requirement already satisfied: sqlalchemy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.3.17)
```

Strangely, `flask run` does work.

I am using vscode and `python3.7.4-64bit`. How may I solve this problem?

here is the my `pip3 freeze`

```
~/Documents/cs50_web/project1 » pip3 freeze                                                                                                  1 ↵ macone@Macs-MacBook-Pro
astroid==2.3.3
attrs==19.3.0
autopep8==1.5.2
cachelib==0.1
certifi==2020.4.5.1
cffi==1.14.0
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cryptography==2.9.2
cycler==0.10.0
entrypoints==0.3
flake8==3.7.9
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Session==0.3.2
idna==2.9
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==0.24
jellyfish==0.7.2
Jinja2==2.11.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
lib50==2.0.8
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.2
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.17.4
pexpect==4.8.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.5
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pycparser==2.20
pydocstyle==4.0.1
pyflakes==2.1.1
pylama==7.7.1
pylint==2.4.4
pyparsing==2.4.5
python-dateutil==2.8.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
six==1.13.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.17
submit50==3.0.2
termcolor==1.1.0
typed-ast==1.4.0
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.11.2
```

and `setting.json`

```
{
  "kite.showWelcomeNotificationOnStartup": false,
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": false,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Expressive Theme",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
  "css.remoteStyleSheets": [
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "git.confirmSync": false,
  "python.jediEnabled": false,
  "markdown-preview-enhanced.liveUpdate": true,
  "window.zoomLevel": 1,
  "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
  "files.associations": {
    "*.rmd": "rmd"
    // "*.html": "jinja-html"
  },
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Before the error line, import `sys` and print `sys.path` to see whether the import path is correctly set. Or use `pdb` to debug interactively.

Answer (score 1):

The import error is occurring may be due to the virtual environment problem. You have to use the same virtual environment for any kind of operations with your web app. Try this:

`1. Go to "Web"`

`2. Scroll Down to "Virtualenv:"`

`3. Click on "Start a console in this virtualenv"`

Now use your commands here i.e to install any module using pip or to start the Django/flask shell.

Check more [Here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/20295/)